# Prove that a certain closed subspace of $C[0,1]$ has finite dimension

Tags: functional-analysis

I need to show that if $L \subset C[0, 1]$ is a closed subspace in the $C[0,1]$ norm (i.e. $||f||_{L}=sup|f(x)|$), and all elements of $L$ are continuously differentiable, then L has finite dimension.

I can show:

> $ \exists n \in \mathbb{N}$  such that $\forall f \in L, \lVert f \rVert=1
> > \Rightarrow \lVert f'\rVert \le n$

But I need to conclude from this that the mapping $\psi :L \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{4n+1}$ is injective, where $\psi: f \mapsto(f(0), f(1/4n), f(2/4n), ... , f(1))$

And I have no idea how to prove the injectivity of $\psi$ and I even think that it may not be injective in general. Could you give me a hint how to prove injectivity?

Comment: I know that I can proove that $L$ is finite dimensional easier, but I need to prove exactly that $dimL \le 4n+1$ where $n$ is from my post

Comment: what happen if $L=C^1[a,b]$ ?

Comment: Oh, I meant $L \subset C[0, 1]$-closed subspace and all functions from $L$ are continuously differentiable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f\in L$ satisfy $\psi(f) = (0,\ldots,0)$, i.e., $f(k/4n)=0$ for $0\leq k \leq 4n$.

Suppose for contradiction that $f\neq 0$. By compactness we may find $x_0$ such that $|f(x_0)| = \|f\|$ for some $x_0\in (0,1)$.  Since $L$ is a subspace we may rescale so that $|f(x_0)|=1$.

Now you can use the mean value theorem applied to the subinterval containing $x_0$, to find $x_k$ such that $|f'(x_k)| > \frac{1}{1/4n}$ and hence $\|f'\| > 4n$, a contradiction to the fact about $L$ which you were able to prove.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it really worked!